# Application authorize and authenticate user with database

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

I am writing a multi-user-application in Delphi (Object Pascal).

I want to use either MySql, Oracle or PostgreSQL as database.

I have a table `Users` with a username and password column.
(I do **not** want to have seperate DB logins for each user)

Of course the application itself has to connect to the database and authorize users by the entered username and password combination.

Software like SAP, Sage or Social Networks would use the same approach, i would guess?

So the application has to know a DB login username and password to connect to the database and then check the `Users` table.

---

My question is:

Where do i save the DB login username and password for the application so it can check the `Users` table?
I do not want to hardcode it in the application as it can be easily accessed by reverse engineering and then used to directly connect to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, your best approach is to follow best security practices around your server.  You could use a salt, but the hash function will have to live on the server, too, and if a hacker has access to the server in the first place then it won't be long before they find the hash and pull the password.

I think efficient organization actually produces some security through obscurity.  That is, put the DB connect credentials and string in a config file.  Still, access to the application code will give a hacker the clues to get what they want, but it doesn't mean you shouldn't follow best coding practices.

Then, lock down your box.  Work with your security team to make sure it isn't accessible by anyone they don't want accessing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i won't be able to sleep well if my application uses security through obscurity.

Comment: LOL, well, it won't.  My point is that if a hacker has access to your box you have a whole lot more to worry about.  If you want security then you put it between the hacker and the box, not between the application and the DB.